# How can I get rid of Google Analytics spam on the dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, spam-prevention

Website: https:deeringwealthteam.com/

I opened Google Analytics this morning to find that the "Language" section had been spammed ... **on the dashboard**.

[Trump spam in Google Analytics "Language" section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZlg7.png)

Would someone have had to insert that text into the `lang` attribute of whatever site linked to mine?

My real question is this: **How can I remove this outlier from my data?** The site is still fairly new, and we don't invest heavily in promoting it, but I want what little data I have to be reliable.

*Side note: I'm new to web development and still learning. This site was built with WordPress. I would've loved to code it, but there wasn't time and I have multiple responsibilities outside of website maintenance, so any additional tips are appreciated.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about google analytics spam and is not programing related.

Comment: You need to Google "remove google referral spam" from Analytics.